# custom ostream that will call the function with string as argument

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I come from ActionScript so I am not so keen on C++. But I think this can be achievable, but I dont know how.

I am using one library, where you declare ostream as standard output. Now, in all examples, ostream is set to cout, but I want to handle the string by myself.

I was wandering, if it is possible that once the library does `ostream << "string"`
that I get something like

```
function handleString (string output){
// handle output
}
```

so that I can handle it here.

---

How can I set ostream to call the function with the string as argument?

---

Examples from lib.

In header I have

```
class Lib {
ostream* m_Output; // The output stream
```

...

```
public:
    inline void SetOutputStream(ostream* o){ m_Output = o; m_Output->precision(2); *m_Output << fixed; }
```

Example of implementation

```
*m_Output << "Some string output" << endl;
```

Example of example CLI app that uses the lib, how it sets the output stream

```
Validator->SetOutputStream(&cout); // Set output to std::cout
```

I want to do something like this

```
Validator->SetOutputStream(ostreamObjectThatWillCallMyFunctionAsString);
```

Comment: What is the problem you have faced? Mention the problem clearly in the question.

Comment: did it, added more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the description it seems you just want to build a string and process this. You can do so using string streams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
void f(std::ostream& out) { out << "f()"; }
int main() {
    std::ostringstream out;
    f(out);
    std::cout << "string='" << out.str() << "'\n";
    f(std::cout);
}
```

If you want to have a function called automatically upon certain events happening to a stream, e.g., when it is flushed, you'd use a custom stream buffer and create an `std::ostream` with that. I'd only call the function on flushes or, maybe, on newlines. Otherwise you either get a call for each character or somewhat unpredictable behavior. Here is a quick example:

```
class funbuf:
    public std::streambuf {
    std::string buffer;
    std::function<void(std::string const&)> fun;
public:
    funbuf(std::function<void(std::string const&)> fun)
        : fun(fun) {}
    int overflow(int c) {
        if (c != std::char_traits<char>::eof()) {
            buffer.push_back(c);
             // this->fun(this->buffer); // for each char
        }
        return std::char_traits<char>::not_eof(c);
    }
    int sync() {
        this->fun(this->buffer);
        return 0;
    }
};
void process(std::string const& s) {
    std::cout << "process(" << s << ")\n";
}
int main() {
    funbuf sbuf(&process);
    std::ostream out(&sbuf);
    out << "one " << 1 << "\n" << std::flush;
    out << std::unitbuf << "three " << 3 << '\n';
}
```

Thus should be a working example (it is untested and typed on a phone, i.e., probably riddled with typos). The demo shows flushing the stream explicitly and implicitly using `std::unitbuf`. A variation may be to reset the buffer after cslling the function which is easily achieved by adding

```
this->buffer.clear();
```

At a strategic point. Likewise, calls to the function if the string is empty can eadily be avoided.

Comment: But this would not call `f` every time the Lib makes an output to stream. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Correct. If you want to get a function called every time an output is made you'd create a stream buffer and override the `overflow()` and `sync()` methods.

Comment: This is the approach I want to have, but I am not so good in c++ so I will need some time to implement it in my case :) But this answers my question, and streamBuffer is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you probably want to overload the << operator.
This should work:

```
class Lib
{
    std::ostream *m_Output;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(const Lib &, const std::string &);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(const Lib &lib, const std::string &s)
{
    if(lib.m_Output)
    {
        lib.m_Output->write(s.c_str(), s.length());
    }

    return *lib.m_Output;
}
```

Comment: could be, I will try :)

Comment: This will crash as you call "operator<<" inside "operator<<", that is an infinite recursion.

Comment: Is this possible without changing the lib?

Comment: do you mean editing your already existing code or are you talking about constness?

Comment: I mean, implementing this without changing the `Lib` c++. I would like to do this by doing all the code needed in my main class that uses `Lib`

Comment: you need a way of letting the overloaded operator access m_Output. so you can either mark it as a friend or make m_Output public. or you could instead implement a GetOutputStream method.